# OOP design: Proper way to statically specify value for inherited property

Tags: oop, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a OOP design question to ask that's probably fairly elementary. I was unable to find the answer to my question through Google, but I think that's more a consequence of not being able to phrase my keywords right - hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction. The question actually applies to a larger project, but I'll simplify it to the bare minimum.

```
class Animal
{
    private string sound;
    
    public getSound()
    {
         return this.sound;
    }

    public setSound(string newSound)
    {
        this.sound = newSound;
    }
}
```

I have an `Animal` class with a `private sound` property and an accompanying getter/setter pair. How do I design a `Dog` class that inherits from `Animal`, so that it specifies the `sound` property as `"bark"` and, crucially, *prevents it from being changed*?

Here are a two options I could think of:

A) Set the property statically and remove/hide setter, i.e.:

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
         this.sound = "bark";
    }
    
    // Hide this
    private setSound(string newSound)
    {
        this.sound = newSound;
    }
}
```

No language I know of allows this, because it breaks Liskov.

B) Overload setter to do nothing or throw exception:

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog()
    {
         this.sound = "bark";
    }
    
    // Either
    public setSound(string newSound)
    {
    }

    // Or
    public setSound(string newSound)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperation("Dogs can't not bark");
    }
}
```

The former is a code smell and both again break Liskov.

Some context: The actual problem is having a class hierarchy that generates code, specifically nested arrays in PHP, such as `$myArr = ['a'=> ..., 'b' => ...]`. In this particular example, I would basically have a class representing `$myArr` which would have fields `$a` and `$b`, with getters/setters for both (I'm simplifying a little for the sake of brevity). What I need is the ability to create a `$mySpecificArr`, where e.g. `$a` would be statically set to some value, and only `$b` could be set dynamically.

What's the proper way to approach this problem?

Comment: some code would be great for other people which want to learn from your question.

Comment: Well, I'd be happy to do that, except I don't know the solution :)

Comment: Added some code to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'm guessing removing the setter is not an option?